# Padding Top Causing Margin Outside Div - Understanding the DOM

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, padding

I'm a coding student and I think I've been making some great progress but recently I ran into an issue that I just can't figure out.

First of all, consider the page located [HERE](http://nexteratech.org/index.php/networking-administration/).

This is a page that I was working up for one of my projects. I found a trick to preserve aspect ratio found [HERE](https://voormedia.com/blog/2012/11/responsive-background-images-with-fixed-or-fluid-aspect-ratios), and was trying to make use of it to get the look I wanted.

Unexpectedly, making use of this trick in my case caused an unwanted margin in the containing div at the bottom of the display. I tried various methods to remedy this issue to no avail. Finally, I just chose to use jQuery to make the issue go away. The code I used is as follows:

HTML:

```js
(function($) {
  var thingHeight = $('#mainPic').css("height");
  $('#thing').css("height", thingHeight);
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#opacity {
  background-color: #c5d8d8;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.4;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#mainPic {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url('http://nexteratech.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/43146453_314512212434998_6895115624842788864_n.jpg');
  padding-top: 33.3%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
}

#mainHeaderText {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 250px;
  text-decoration: underline #97ef94;
  color: #00353f;
  font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  left: 20px;
}

#headerParagraph {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 249px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #003366
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="opacity"></div>

<div id="mainPic">
  <h1 id="mainHeaderText">NETWORKING & ADMINISTRATION SOLUTIONS
  </h1>
  <p id="headerParagraph">Affordable I.T., server, and cloud solutions for any business size.</p>
</div>
```

This too did not result in changing anything. I went through a series of diagnostic test and theories to try to figure out the problem with no resolution. The jquery was working fine, it wasn't my theme (Avada), the css was all typed correctly etc, but still nothing. Finally, I just went ahead and gave #mainPic a height value, something I was hoping to avoid to allow for mobile-friendly adaptation, and voila! Unwanted margin disappeared.

What I want to know is why? What was causing the margin in the first place, why didn't jquery change it, and why did it disappear even when #mainPic had a height of 0?

Please be forgiving my ignorance and the length of this question. Thank you for any help in advance. :)

Comment: In the sample provided, the margin on the `#mainPic` is the default margin of the body element. Use a css reset and the problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to tell exactly *why* with the snippets you provided. You can also try to re-create your issue inside of a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for us & it might help rule out if its any external libraries affecting your site.

A tool I love to use for debugging margin issues and the like is the [Pesticide for Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pesticide-for-chrome/bblbgcheenepgnnajgfpiicnbbdmmooh) by Paul Molluzo